# How to make real-time dashboard in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, aws-iot

I am trying to make a dashboard to listen iot device status in Laravel.

Front-end uses Vue.js to trigger the Laravel API every minute. And the API will to access AWS iot shadow

[Architecture diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQxBx.png)

But I want to make it more instant.

Do I have any mechanism to monitor the data for changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot build a real-time application with Laravel only. You need to use for example socket.io, **pusher**. However, Laravel provides wrappers for these technologies, you've might have heard of Laravel Echo. If you want to understand how to build your desired real-time application a good place to start is to first read about broadcasting in Laravel.

So yeah **PUSHER** can do the trick